# Como encerrar socket dentro de um loop infinito?

Tags: java, socket, multithreading

Olá, eu criei um projeto servidor-cliente usando um socket que fica escutando na porta e envia o elemento de uma "Queue" até que a fila não possua mais elementos. No entanto, quando eu encerro a aplicação do cliente, o servidor continua aberto e escutando. O problema é que eu terei que inserir esse programa em outra aplicação e mesmo que eu feche a aplicação, a porta continuará aberta e escutando. O que eu deveria fazer para resolver isso?

Aqui está o código:

Servidor:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = new Connection();
        new Thread(conn).start();
    }

    private static class Connection implements Runnable {
        Queue<MovementCommand> commandQueue = new LinkedList<>();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5005)) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                listener(socket);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void listener(Socket socket) {
            commandQueue.add(new MovementCommand("Point-0001", "NOP"));
            commandQueue.add(new MovementCommand("Point-0002", "NOP"));
            commandQueue.add(new MovementCommand("Point-0004", "NOP"));
            commandQueue.add(new MovementCommand("Point-0008", "NOP"));
            commandQueue.add(new MovementCommand("Point-0011", "NOP"));

            boolean alive = true;
            MovementCommand curCommand;

            while (alive) {
                try {
                     DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                     DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                     curCommand = this.commandQueue.poll();

                    if (curCommand != null) {
                       outputStream.writeUTF(curCommand.getPoint() + " - " + curCommand.getOperation());

                       String data = inputStream.readUTF();
                       System.out.println("New reported position: " + data);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    alive = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cliente:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5005)) {
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            boolean alive = true;

            while (alive) {
                try {
                    String data = inputStream.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Incoming data: " + data);

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    outputStream.writeUTF(data.substring(0, 10));
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    alive = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Grato desde já!!

Comment: O que é e pra que serve `curCommand`?

Comment: É o comando atual que o servidor tem que enviar. Os comandos estão enfileirados e ele envia o próximo quando o cliente confirma que recebeu. É só pra exemplificar, porque é para um projeto de controle de robôs

Comment: E como o servidor sabe que há um cliente conectado? Ou ele não sabe?

Comment: Eu acho que o servidor assume que ele possui um cliente conectado quando ele executa o método `serverSocket.accept();`. Na verdade o servidor só espera a conexão de um cliente, a thread serve para não travar a interface gráfica do outro programa que está por baixo.

Comment: Pelo que estou lendo na documentação, a classe `ServerSocket` é fechada após as conexoes com ela se encerrarem. Não está ocorrendo isso? Já tentou ver se cai no bloco catch do servidor ao encerrar?

Comment: Ele só lança a exceção que está no método `run()` se o cliente não conseguir se conectar(ex: porta ocupada). Ele nunca lança a exceção do método `listener()`, então ele mantêm o socket sempre aberto, mesmo que o cliente desconecte

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71190/discussion-between-andre-spironello-and-articuno).